# Fuel SDK Endpoint settings

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, c#

I've downloaded the C# SFMC Fuel SDK and I'm stuck at a rather ignominious place. Where do I get the end points? I looked at [this link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/your-subdomain-tenant-specific-endpoints.htm), but where am I supposed to get the appSignature, clientID and clientSecret from?

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="fuelSDK" type="FuelSDK.FuelSDKConfigurationSection, FuelSDK" />
  </configSections>
  <fuelSDK 
    appSignature="<appSignature>" 
    clientId="<clientId>" 
    clientSecret="<clientSecret>" 
    authEndPoint="<authenticationEndPoint>" 
    soapEndPoint="<soapEndPoint>" 
    restEndPoint="<restEndPoint>" />
</configuration>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Administration->Account->Installed Packages you need to create a package for API. Once you create it, it will have the client id and client secret. Also, the authentication endpoint would be there.
The format would be:
https://.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token

Comment: I tried it with:
{ "clientId", "..." },
{ "clientSecret", "..." },
{ "authEndPoint", "https://blah.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token" },
{ "soapEndPoint", "https://blah.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx" },
{ "restEndPoint", "https://blah.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/" },

But I get 400 Bad request, seen this before?

Comment: @mercifulhop The c# sdk has been updated to handle the new oAuth 2.0 code now